# Search multiple beans with one input text

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I want to use one `h:inputText` to call search methods in multiple beans. User is asked to type a place name in the `h:inputText`, `place` is a variable in all beans, each searchMethod then finds records with place criteria.
Questions are first: How do I call multiple beans methods for one `h:inputText` and without a `h:commandButton`? Second: How do I redirect to a search page with all results grouped by bean names after pressing Enter by user?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544335/jsf2-search-box) SO question regarding using `h:inputText` without `h:commandButton` but how do I call multiple beans and how do I redirect to `search_results.xhtml` page.

I'm using jsf 2.2

**Update**
I wrote bellow code but I don't know how to set render attribute so that it redirects to search.xhtml page. I've set it to `place` which is the id of input text and it just reloads the page.

```
<h:inputText id="place" value="#{bean.place}"
     onkeypress="if(event.keyCode === 13){onchange(event); return false;}"
     onchange="return event.keyCode !== undefined">
     <f:param name="place" value="#{bean.place}"/>                                            
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.goToSearch}" render="place"/>
</h:inputText>
```

goToSearch():

```
public String goToSearch(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){                
    return "Search.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true";
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to do it in multiple beans. It's just against JSF working methodology. Just use an action method in a `@ViewScoped` managed bean and invoke as many controllers as you want from there.

Comment: Thanks @XtremeBiker It's a good idea. How about redirecting to another page?

Comment: Just return `"search_results?faces-redirect=true"` in your action method once you've finished your server side job.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Thanks for your comment. I added some workaround to my question. I still didn't manage it to work.

Comment: I used `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect"Search.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true"` and it worked.