# jsf ajax valueChange event only firing when hitting enter key

Tags: ajax, jsf, valuechangelistener

I've created a textField with JSF and want it to update a table `myTable` when the user inserts a String.

I've tried this

```
    <h:inputText id="searchHeader" value="#{myBean.searchStringFirstname}" 
             valueChangeListener="#{myBean.searchByFirstnameValueChanged}"  >
        <f:ajax render="myTable"/>
    </h:inputText>
```

and this

```
    <h:inputText id="searchHeader" value="#{myBean.searchStringFirstname}">
        <f:ajax listener="#{myList.searchByFirstname}" event="valueChange"
            execute="myTableForm" render="myTable" />
    </h:inputText>
```

I want the event to fire every time the value of the InputField gets changed, but in both cases the eventListener method specified by `valueChangeListener` only gets called when the user hits the enter key.

Why is that?

I've tried this solution [JSF2 search box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544335/jsf2-search-box) but I could not make it work.

Comment: *"I want the event to fire every time the value of the InputField gets changed"* I believe you actually meant to say "I want the event to fire every time the user releases the key press on the input field". Is this true? Because, it is behaving exactly as you coded it and thus there's absolutely no technical problem here. Just your own misconception.

Comment: exactly. Based on this, am I right to assume that `keyup` is the event I am looking for here?

Comment: Depends on the technical requirement which you still didn't tell anything about. But yes, it's one of the candiates. Start learning basic HTML / JS / DOM to figure out the answer you're actually looking for.